# How to use a drop down in mvc with same model used twice for create and edit

Tags: visual-studio-2012, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I have dropdown with model `address.countryID` which I used for creating a form and another dropdown for popUp for edit in same view

Since both have the same Name for dropdown (modelName) so the second DropDown is not working

If I change the name the value is not updating as it does not match the Model property

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.CountryID)
            .Name("Address.CountryID") //Note If i change name the value vont come
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("CountryRegionCode")
            .BindTo(new List<RGBSIPayDummy.Models.Country>(ViewBag.Countries))
)
```

Comment: "Address.CountryID" is a string Uou can't name DropDownList with parameter like 1,2,3. you have two dropDownList with name  Address.CountryID not id 1 and 2.

Comment: It is not correct to define a `Kendo().DDLFor()` with the `.Name()` property. As the name property will overwrite the for and cause Model binding issues

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot use the same DOM name for two elements, because JavaScript (that Kendo is dependent upon) cannot figure out which DOM element to call, so it fails, or just does one of them.

The pop-up window is HTML code that gets added to your main page's HTML code, so all of it should be treated like it was that way to begin with.  So, you wouldn't name them the same name if it was there to start. :)

What I do in these cases where you have the same field, but 2 or more instances of it is to prefix the field like this:

```
 modal.Address.CountryID
```

And when receiving that on the Controller side, you just have a different model to support the AJAX post from the Modal window that supports the fields you are adding.  That way, everything is clean and JavaScript isn't confused.